# Find all functions s.t.$f(x^2-y^2)=xf(x)-yf(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functions such that $\forall x,y\in \mathbb R$ $$f(x^2-y^2)=xf(x)-yf(y)$$
It’s obvious that $f(0)=0$, and by setting $x=0$ then $y=0$, we get
$$\cases{f(x^2)=xf(x) \\ f(-y^2)=-yf(x)=-f(y^2)}$$
Hence $$f(x^2-y^2)=f(x^2)-f(y^2)$$
My guess is that $f(x)=x$, but I don’t know if that’s the only solution.

Comment: [This](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/FuncEq-Intro/FuncEq-Intro.pdf) should do

Comment: “Plugging in -x for y”, In what equation did you substitute it?

Comment: The OP in that question doesn't want to find all solutions @MohsenShahriari

Comment: @Yassir It seems that he/she does want to find all the solutions, as his/her attempt is towards proving $f(x)=ax$ for nonnegative $x$, and one can easily see that $f(x)=ax$ gives a solution. Also, the OP implicitly uses continuity, which is not given, and asks whether that is valid. And finally, the answer characterizes all the solutions.

Comment: Can you re-suggest ''Does this answer your question''? so that I can choose ''yes'' @MohsenShahriari

Comment: @Yassir I've already voted for marking this thread as a duplicate of the linked post, and that's why you've received the "Does this answer your question" message, and an automatically generated comment has appeared under the post. I can't vote again on that for a long time. I think you can do that by yourself, by clicking on the "Flag" appearing under the post, and choosing "a duplicate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from what you found, we can set $a = x^2$ and $b = y^2$. Now, we have
$$f(a - b) = f(a) - f(b)$$

With $a = 0$, we have $f(-b) = -f(b)$, so $f(b)$ is odd. Which permits to write

$$f(a - (-b)) = f(a+b) = f(a) - f(-b) = f(a) + f(b)$$

Also, notice that, if $a = b$, $f(a - b) = f(a - a) = f(0) = f(a) - f(a) = 0$, so we also proved that $f(0) = 0$.

Knowing the two pieces of information we just proved, some people would directly state that $f(a) = ma$, $m \in \mathbb{R}$, but let's prove that these two statements are equivalent. Manipulating $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$, we can write the following:

$$f(a + b) - f(a) = f(b) - f(0) \Leftrightarrow \frac{f(a + b) - f(a)}{b} = \frac{f(0 + b) - f(0)}{b}$$

Up here, we can add $f(0)$ because $f(0) = 0$, and then we divide by $b \neq 0$. The cool fact here, is that we ended up to the definition of the derivative, when $\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}$. So, we can write,

$$\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}\ \frac{f(a + b) - f(a)}{b} = \lim_{b\rightarrow 0} \ \frac{f(0 + b) - f(0)}{b} = f'(a) = f'(0)$$

What this line tells us, is that the derivative of $f(a)$ is a constant: $f'(0)$, which means that $f(a)$ is equal to $ma + c$, but we also know that $f(0) = 0 = m\times 0 + c \Leftrightarrow c = 0$, so $f(a) = ma$.

By putting back the variable $x$, we have $f(x^2) = mx^2 \Leftrightarrow f(x) = mx$ with $m \in \mathbb{R}$

So, as you said, $f(x) = x$ is a valid solution, like $f(x) = \pi x$ is.

Comment: In general, it is not possible to conclude that $f(x) = mx$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ from the condition that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$; in your solution, you have made the implicit assumption that $f$ is differentiable. See the Wikipedia article on [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the general case, but here's a solution that assumes $f$ is continuous at $1$. Fix some $a > 0$. Your first functional equation, $f(x^2) = xf(x)$, implies that $$f(a) = \sqrt{a} f(\sqrt{a}).$$ Applying this functional equation again yields $$f(a) = a^{3/4} f(a^{1/4}).$$ Iterated applications of the functional equation in this way then yields, in general, $$f(a) = a^k f(a^{\frac{1}{2^n}}),$$ where $k = \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-i}$. Thus, $$\frac{f(a)}{a^k} = f(a^{\frac{1}{2^n}})$$ for all $k$. As $n \to \infty$, $k \to 1$, so the LHS tends to $f(a)/a$, while the right-hand side tends to $f(1)$ (since $f$ is continuous at $1$). Thus, $$f(a) = ca$$ for some constant $c$ for all $a > 0$. Since you have already shown that $f(0) = 0$, your second functional equation $f(-y^2) = -f(y^2)$ then extends this relation for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Addendum: Your final equation, $f(x^2 - y^2) = f(x^2) - f(y^2)$, is equivalent to Cauchy's functional equation $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$. Therefore, any of the following additional assumptions on $f$ would allow you to conclude that $f$ is linear (according to Wikipedia):

1. $f$ is continuous at some point.
2. $f$ is bounded on any interval.
3. $f$ is monotonic on any interval.
4. $f$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Without some additional assumption, you cannot conclude that $f$ is linear, and in fact nonlinear solutions to this functional equation exist. The question is whether or not your first equation $f(x^2 - y^2) = xf(x) - yf(y)$ is a stronger condition than $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$, which I assume it must be (because otherwise, you probably wouldn't be asking this question). However, I'm not entirely sure how you would go about proving that.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is using calculus. For any fixed $y$, if you derivate the expression $f(x^2-y^2)=xf(x)-yf(y)$ with respect to $x$, you get
$$ 2xf'(x^2-y^2) = f(x) + xf'(x).$$

Since this holds for every $y$, in particular, taking $y=x^2$ (and using that $f(0)=0)$, this yields
$$ f(x) = -xf'(x) = -\frac{xdf}{dx}$$

Combining with the fact that $f(0)=0$, we have the EDO
$$ -\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{df}{f}, \quad f'(0)=0.$$
Now solving this EDO yields the general solution $f(x)=cx+b$, but the initial condition $f'(0)=0$ implies that $b=0$, and therefore you must get the same $f(x)=cx$.